# "out of gas" when trying to send back ETH from a contract to tx.origin

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, out-of-gas, solidity-0.7.x

**(UPDATED)**

The contract should have more than enough ETH. I deploy the contract with 0.1 ETH: https://git.io/JUBdy

`const consumerExample = await ConsumerExampleFactory.deploy(process.env.REGISTRATION_GATEWAY_ADDRESS, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1") });`

The contract then sends a transaction with a value of 100 wei to another contract: https://git.io/JUBd9

```
constructor(address simplorRegistrationGatewayAddress) SimplorConsumer(simplorRegistrationGatewayAddress) payable {
    registerSimplorEvent("RequestEthPriceEvent");
}
```

and

```
function registerSimplorEvent(string memory eventName) public payable {
  _registrationGateway.registerEvent{ value: 100 }(
    eventName,
    address(this)
  );
}
```

Then an event is triggered (https://git.io/JUBd7) to which a node responds (https://git.io/JUBd5) to fulfillInt (https://git.io/JUBdF) which then (in the `SimplorFulfill` modifier) is supposed to send 100 wei back to the node's address (https://git.io/JUBdN).

Calling the method that triggers the event:

```
const ethPrice = await consumerExample.requestEthPrice()
```

A node listening for it and sending back data:

```
consumers[callbackContractAddress].methods[fulfillTypeMethod](fulfillCallback, response.value, requestId, response.requestPrice).send({
  from: process.env.NODE_ACCOUNT
}).then(tx => { ...
```

(`fulfillTypeMethod` = `"fulfilInt"`, `response.requestPrice` = `100`)

The receiving function:

```
function fulfillInt(
  bytes4 fulfillCallback,
  uint256 value,
  uint256 requestId,
  uint256 requestPrice
) external onlySimplOracle SimplorFulfill(requestId, requestPrice) {...
```

and finally in it's second modfier:

```
modifier SimplorFulfill(uint256 requestId, uint256 requestPrice) {
  // check/increase confirmations
  require(_simplorCurrentResponses[requestId] < _simplorRequiredResponses[requestId], "Request already confirmed.");
  require(address(this).balance > requestPrice, "Consumer does not have enough ETH to pay for the fulfillment.");
  _simplorCurrentResponses[requestId]++;
  // transfer 100 wei (TODO: calculate/set fees)
  payable(tx.origin).transfer(requestPrice); // This seems to cause the "out ouf gas" error.

  _;
}
```

**UPDATE** I added the second `require(...)` to check if the consumer has anough ETH.

Causes: `Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas`

Remember the contract was deployed with 0.1 ETH and already managed to send 100 Wei to the `_registrationGateway` when calling `registerSimplorEvent` in its constructor.

The `requestPrice` comes from another package (https://git.io/JUBb9):

```
return {
  value: result.data.ethereum.usd * 100,
  type: 'int', // currently supported: 'bool', 'int' and 'string'
  requestPrice: 100 // Wei
}
```

Here is my repository with the full code: https://github.com/mktcode/simplor/blob/master/contracts/SimplorConsumer.sol#L81

Comment: Your problem is not in the aforementioned line of code.

Comment: @goodvibration Hm.... but I reduced the code to basically what you see above and it really seems to depend on this line. But you are saying it is not in the provided code because that simply must work? I'll investigate further now... Also feel free to take a look at the repository. The full code is there.

Comment: I did, and I was not convinced that you had correctly "tracked the issue down to this push".

Comment: In addition to that, things like `if (_simplorCurrentResponses[requestId] == _simplorRequiredResponses[requestId])` made me wonder if you had any idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Ehmm... I'm learning. Sorry for that. Maybe you can explain why this is bad?

Comment: First off, it's not about being bad, it's about being pointless. What could you possibly hope to achieve with `if (x == x)`??? Second, what exactly is the meaning of `_simplorCurrentResponses[requestId]` to begin with? It's an array, how is that comparable with anything???

Comment: Where do you see `(x == x)`? What the code does and if it works or makes any sense... can this please not be the focus here? I'm pretty sure I can write some code that has potential to work... I'm doing that for a few years. And if you see possible improvements or bugs or typos or whatever... I appreciate. I am learning solidity for about two weeks now and my experimental learning project is an own oracle system. Just for fun/learning...
Oh and... `_simplorCurrentResponses[requestId]` is not an array, it's an int256. `simplorIntResponses` and so on are the mappings with arrays.

Comment: Yeah, after a careful look, `_simplorCurrentResponses` and `_simplorRequiredResponses` are different symbols. May I suggest you use more distinguishable names? In either case, you have a ton of other stuff in that code, so I suggest you try again to filter out where that error is stemming from.

Comment: I'm on it. Trying to isolate it more clearly. But in any case... You say that above code SHOULD generally work? You don't see any flaws there? Anything related to ABIEncoderV2 or that stuff? I'm not yet that familiar with all of that...

Comment: Not that I can see.

Comment: You are completely right... it's not that line. Idk where I mixed up things and thought that that was the case. Anyway... seems to be the `SimplorFulfill` modifier. The transfer to tx.origin...

Comment: So the contract does not have enough ETH to send something back... Anyway... I think I can progress from here.

Comment: The contract should have more than enough ETH. Let me explain... I deploy the contract with 0.1 ETH: https://git.io/JUBdy
The contract then sends a transaction with a value of 100 wei to another contract: https://git.io/JUBd9
Then an event is triggered: https://git.io/JUBd7 to which a node responds: https://git.io/JUBd5 to `fulfillInt`: https://git.io/JUBdF which then (in the `SimplorFulfill` modifier) is supposed to send 100 wei back to the node's address: https://git.io/JUBdN

Comment: The requestPrice comes from another package actually (my oracle adapter approach are simply node packages): https://github.com/mktcode/simplor-coingecko-eth-price/blob/master/index.js#L8

Comment: updated the whole question now accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, the below information is only for in-memory arrays as said by @goodvibration.

You're not allocating memory for your array, i.e., you don't instantiate it with the `new` operator, see https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.1/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays.

So when trying to push on an array that wasn't instantiated yet, it will fail.

```
_simplorIntResponses[requestId] = new uint256[]()
```

Comment: That's wrong. This array is in storage, not in memory.

Comment: @goodvibration True.

Comment: And as I mentioned in a comment to the question, the problem is elsewhere (not in the provided code).